# Dynamically created fields with jQuery are deleted at once — they should be deleted one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a questionnaire for which I am generating HTML through jQuery. Below is code of what I have done so far.

I am appending questions in `.add-question` class. I have assigned a counter value on each click. It has `two types`: **text** and **Multiple choice**. When I change its type to **multiple choice**, there should be a link of `add choice`. On clicking `add choice`, a new input field should be generated along with `delete choice link`.

Adding one question is working fine. But when I generate two questions at a time, then change type to `multiple choice`, and then add more `fields`, jQuery starts adding `input fields` in both questions. Upon removing a field, it also removes every input associated with that id.

text type

[image: text type]

changed type to multiple choice

[image: changed type to multiple choice]

Remove choice, On remove choice click it has removed questions 2's input also

[image: Remove choice, On remove choice click it has removed questions 2's input also]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.btn-success').hide();
   var counter = 0;
   var choice = 1;
   $('.btn-add').on('click', function(){
       counter++;
       $('.add-question').append('<br>' + '<div class="question_'+counter+'">'+
               '<div class="form-group">'+
            '<label class="control-label col-md-4" for="question-type">Question Type:</label>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                '<select class="form-control question-type" id="'+counter+'">'+
                    '<option value="text">Text</option>'+
                    '<option value="multiple" id="'+counter+'">Multiple Choice</option>'+
                '</select>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '<div class="form-group">'+
            '<label class="control-label col-md-4" for="question">Enter Question:</label>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                '<input type="text" name="question[]" class="form-control" />'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete " id="'+counter+'">Delete Question</button>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="form-group txt-answer'+counter+'">'+
            '<label class="control-label col-md-4" for="answer">Answer:</label>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                '<input type="text" name="answer[]" id="answer" class="form-control" />'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<hr>'+
        '<div>'+
        '</div>'
        );
     $('.btn-success').show();   
   });

   $(document).on('click', '.btn-delete' , function() {
       var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
       $('.question_'+buttonId).remove();
       if($('.question_'+buttonId) === "undefined") {
       $('.btn-success').hide();
   }
   });


   $(document).on('change', '.question-type' , function(){
//      var value = $('#question-type').val();
      var value = $(this).attr("id");

      if($(this).val() === "multiple")  {
          $('.txt-answer'+value).replaceWith('<div class="form-group remove-choice'+choice+'">'+    
            '<label class="control-label col-md-4" for="choice">Choice '+choice+':</label>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                '<input type="text" name="choice[]" id="choice" class="form-control" />'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-2 add-choice">'+
            '<label class="" for="choice"></label>'+
                '<input type="checkbox" name="flag[]" id="flag" /> Correct?'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-remove" id="'+choice+'">Delete Choice</button>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<button type ="button" class="btn btn-link col-md-offset-4 btn-choice">Add Choice</button>'+
        '</div>'
        );
      } else if($(this).val() === "text") {
          var choiceId = $(this).attr("id");
          $('.remove-choice'+choiceId).replaceWith('<div class="form-group">'+
            '<label class="control-label col-md-4" for="answer">Answer:</label>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                '<input type="text" name="answer[]" id="answer" class="form-control" />'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>');
      }
   });

   $(document).on('click', '.btn-choice', function() {
     choice++;
      $('<div class="form-group remove-choice'+choice+'">'+     
            '<label class="control-label col-md-4" for="choice">Choice '+choice+':</label>'+
            '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                '<input type="text" name="choice[]" id="choice" class="form-control" />'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-2">'+
            '<label class="" for="choice"></label>'+
                '<input type="checkbox" name="flag[]" id="flag'+choice+'" /> Correct?'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-remove" id="'+choice+'">Delete Choice</button>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<br>'+
        '</div>').insertBefore('.btn-choice'); 
   });

   $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', function() {
       var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
       $('.remove-choice'+buttonId).remove();
   });
});
```

**EDIT:**

I have add my code to fiddle please check it and tell me how can i make it better?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7b24Lq1s/)

Comment: Ok, this is a pretty big snipplet to go through without a working example of the issue.  One thing I do see that is kinda interesting is in the question type change logic.  You are using the global `choice` variable in the replace with logic.  So if I am reading this right, if you have 10 question areas and you change the type on any of them, it would then use the last choice value, regardless of which question type you changed.

Comment: This is the real issue i am assigning `choice number` to its relevant class and on the basis of that i am manipulating things. How it can be improved.

Comment: You could experiment with putting the needed contextual values on the elements as data-* fields.  Such as data-choice="#" .  Then in the event for the element you could get that contextual value with `$(element).data('choice')`

Comment: is not there any other way rather than using `data` element?

Comment: @Taplar I have added JSfiddle link Please check it. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing .insertBefore(this); instead of .insertBefore('.btn-choice'); solve adding choice to all multiple choices questions. But still there is a problem. It is the counter problem, it is same all of multiple choices questions. And we can solve this adding an attribute "data-choiceCount" for all 'btn-choice's.Then we can use it for choice count when btn-choice button is clicked.

[Here fiddle is](https://jsfiddle.net/7b24Lq1s/2/)

Changed Lines

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-choice', function() {
  var choice = parseInt($(this).attr('data-choiceCount')) + 1;
  $(this).attr('data-choiceCount', choice);
  $('<div class="form-group remove-choice'+choice+'">'+     
        '<label class="control-label col-md-4" for="choice">Choice '+choice+':</label>'+
        '<div class="col-md-4">'+
            '<input type="text" name="choice[]" id="choice" class="form-control" />'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="col-md-2">'+
        '<label class="" for="choice"></label>'+
            '<input type="checkbox" name="flag[]" id="flag'+choice+'" /> Correct?'+
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-remove" id="'+choice+'">Delete Choice</button>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<br>'+
    '</div>').insertBefore(this); 
  });
```

Comment: how can we add this `data-choiceCount` and then use it?

Comment: I add that attr where you create btn-choice in js. You can see in fiddle. It is in if($(this).val() === "multiple")  { scope. It is '<button type ="button" class="btn btn-link col-md-offset-4 btn-choice" data-choiceCount="0">Add Choice</button>'

Comment: ok this is working fine when i add a `choice` and `remove`. But when i change the type again from `multiple choice` to text. it does not work. @Hakan SONMEZ

Comment: It does not work on your origin fiddle. So that's another problem and it must be another question.

Comment: Everything is working fine now except the `dropdown` it can be solved here then why do we need another question? @Hakan SONMEZ

Comment: Because this site is not your debugger, it helps solving the specific problem. But this time I have fixed many bugs on your script. I hope it helps you. [New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7b24Lq1s/6/)